# Custom class ideology / design

Tags: python, oop, methodology

I have two objects `profile1` and `profile2` that both inherit from a generic class called `profile`. Many `profile2`s can relate to a `profile1` but only 1 `profile1` can relate to a `profile2`. For the most part they have similar functionality and inherit most of their behavior from `profile`.

My question is would it be better to create two subclasses or just keep them all as generic profiles and include a `profiletype` property that could be `1` or `2`. Subclassing presents a challenge because I can't seem to figure out how to code a method that allows them to change their type.

```
def changeProfileType(self, Profiletype):
    if profiletype == 0:
        # this is the generic profile. So if 0, create a new generic profile
        # with the same name
        return Profile.__init__(self, self.name)
    elif profiletype == 1:
        #if 1, create a Profile1 with the same name
        return Profile1.__init__(self, self.name)
    elif profiletype == 2:
        #if 2, create a Profile2 with the same name
        return Profile2.__init__(self, self.name)
```

If `x` is a `profile1`, `y = x.changeProfileType(2)` makes `y` equal to `Nonetype` instead of a `profile2`.

It would be much easier to not bother with creating new objects and instead keep the original object and change a `profiletype` variable between `0`, `1`, and `2`. It would just create a little code-bloat with having to check that with the specific behaviors. It would also be a lot easier since when I implement collections of `profile` objects, changing the type via objects would be a real pain.

But I feel like that's not very in keeping with OOP.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have only one Profile class with a type that can be changed, you can just have one class with a setter method. I don't see a need for separate Profile classes. Usually you'd do this if the child classes have methods that are new or different from the parent.

```
class Profile:

    def __init__(self, name, pType=0):
        self.name = name
        self.type = pType

    def changeProfileType(self, pType):
        self.type = pType
```

```
profile = Profile("foo")
profile.changeProfileType(2)
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking, but the required functionalities are still kind of undefined right now so it's hard to decide.

Just as a point of curiosity, do you see what's wrong with my OOP approach? Why does it only return NoneType?

Comment: No offense, but it's hard to answer a question when you don't really know what you are trying to do yet :P But to answer why you are seeing None, it's because `__init__` always returns None. If you want to return a new object, I think you can use `__new__` or just call the class directly